# Dynamic Content not working with WP Super Cache

Tags: wordpress, caching

wonder if someone can help. I am trying to add a cart widget to the header of a woocommerce enabled site. However, when WP Super Cache is enabled, the widget doesn't update when something is added to the cart, understandably.

I am trying to add the following so the widget isn't cached:

```
<!--dynamic-cached-content-->
<?php echo time(); ?>
<!-- my_dynamic_content(); -->
<!--/dynamic-cached-content-->
```

I have just displayed the time in this case to see if I can get it working.

I have set the caching to PHP cache, with late init and dynamic caching enabled but the time still doesn't update when I'm logged out of the administrator.

I have trailed through documentation to see if there is another way to get this working but so far I have not found a way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Maybe I've got this completely wrong!

I just want one widget to be dynamic in the header.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: WP Super Cache is not good plugin so avoid to use this plugin

Comment: Are you able to be more constructive with this comment? You say it isn't a good choice but don't explain why nor give a better alternative. The server uses Varnish but as I am using Woocommerce on this site, it'll check for cart cookies and pass to back end when there are items in the cart. This is why I am trying to get dynamic caching to work. Around 70% of the sites visitors add items to the cart, so 70% of users won't have Varnish serving the content so I need to try and reduce the server load by using caching. There is just a header widget that needs to be dynamic, the rest is fine.

Comment: if you think to work with WP Super Cache or w3total this type of plugin then it's not good practice bez they return  problem many time js and CSS problem too.  if you want to protect your code then please code manually

Comment: I've never had an issue with CCS or JS with WP super cache for the last 5 years so I'm sure it'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple types of cache for web applications, and WordPress has ways to take advantage of all of them.

Plugins like WP Super Cache, W3 Total Cache, and Batcache as well as server components like Varnish and Nginx implement *page caching*. These tools store a copy of the complete page and use that cached copy every time the same URL is requested. This is the fastest cache available, but the down side is they return the same HTML to everyone.

**If you want to use a page cache but still have dynamic elements like your header widget, you'll have to render them in JavaScript.**

If you've written your own theme, you can implement *fragment caching* by storing the rendered HTML of different sections of the page except the part you want to be dynamic. There's no plugin you can download that'll do it for you. You'll need to make your own judgement calls about what needs to be cached and for how long.

Lastly, you can just *cache the data* used to render pages. Look for information on WordPress [*persistent object caching*](http://wptavern.com/persistent-object-caching) or write code to use WordPress's Transients API. A persistent object cache plugin can automatically store the results of WordPress's queries to something like Memcached or Redis if you have that available.

Comment: FYI, WP Super Cache has a hook called `cacheaction` that allows you to scan the cached page and update a section dynamically before sending it out to the user.